# Change keywords faces in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, faces

I want to change keywords colors of the AUCTeX package. I found the variable `font-latex-built-in-keyword-classes` that could help me.

If me assume I want to display the keyword "newpage" with the face `new-face`, I've (unsuccessfully) tried that :

```
(setq font-latex-built-in-keyword-classes
  '(("warning"
     ("newpage")
     'new-face 1 noarg)))
```

But it doesn't change nothing. How can I do that ?

Comment: You just evaluated the code or you put it in your init file and restarted Emacs?

Comment: I did both. I tried to evaluate the code and then byte-compiled it in my init file and restarted Emacs. But neither functionned.

Comment: Anyway you should ediy `font-latex-user-keyword-classes`, not the built-in one.  Please note the end of the docstring: "Setting this variable directly does not take effect; use `M-x customize` or restart Emacs."